# What is the difference between an API App and a Web App?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-apps

I've been reading a few tutorials now on deploying Web Apps and API Apps to Azure. However, I am still a little unsure as to why you would use one over another.

I can create a new .NET solution with API controllers and deploy this as a Web App, so why would I specifically require an API App? Are these optimized specifically for ASP.NET Web API, where as Web Apps are for delivering HTML?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Updating the answer to current state of Azure,

App Services now replaces all Mobile, Api and Web Apps flavors as a single app framework with all the functionality rolled over to make things more accessible across application types. **Currently all of Web, Mobile and Api Apps are collectively called App Services.** We still offer customer to be able to create a Mobile App and a Web App in the gallery but that is basically resolve into an App Service App.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-apps-why-best-platform/

Features for Mobile work for Web App as well such as Easy Tables and Easy API. And features for API apps like API Cors and API definitions now work on web apps as well. A customer can host a single web app to act as any mobile service or an api with all the features offered through the app services.

**We also have a new service in preview particularly targeting API Apps by offering a management experience for your APIs, Basically you can control the generate try API pages, gather execution analytics, throttle and much more.** Check out the feature blog to learn more about the Azure API Management Features. And yes you can host the APIs as a App Service App and hook things up with API Management.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/api-management-get-started/

Comment: Kudos for keeping things up to date! Although... Normally I'd think a new answer would be in order, given how much info has been updated vs original answer. Then again, I guess this one's a weird case / gray area though, since it was already upvoted/accepted. :)

Comment: Yes I think updating is good as it keeps the thread fresh and makes sure people see the answer easily :).

Comment: So what the main reason of having API APPs and Web Apps under the umbrella of APP Services if there is no difference

Comment: Another difference: if a developer wants to import an app definition in api management using the Api App option, only web apps created as Api Apps will be available for selection

Answer (score 66):

There was a point in time when there were differences between the different app service types, but that is no longer true.  The [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-apps-why-best-platform/) now states:

> The only difference between the three app types (API, web, mobile) is the name and icon used for them in the Azure portal.

So it no longer matters which app service type you choose to deploy to (unless you care what the icon looks like).

**UPDATE**

Function apps are now the exception.  Creating a function app changes the user interface in the portal.  The underlying web app, however, is no different.  Setting an app setting named `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` = `~1` turns any web app into a function app (minus the user interface in the portal).

Comment: There is another difference. You can't use debugging snappoints on api apps. See the comments from Nikhil_Joglekar_MSFT on Oct 12, 2017 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-live-azure-applications

Comment: @ChibiChakaravarthi How to differentiate whether an app is function app using rest api? I am using this API endpoint : https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}?api-version=2016-08-01
There is kind key in the response, is that key reliable and useful?

Comment: Sadly no. the function app is just another web app. May I know why you want to know the type of the app?

Comment: This is a better, direct answer to the question, i feel.

Answer (score 13):

There are many minor difference between Web API and API Apps, but the very notable and key differences are

1. Native Swagger implementation - When you create API App in Visual studio, swagger reference comes by default. Swagger provide very developer friendly features for API consumers to Interact with your API thru Swagger UI. Also Swagger based API's provides client SDK generation (both .Net based client and Javascript based client) which makes easy to call API's just like regular method call. 
   Note: Swagger implementation on regular Web API is possible manually.
2. Ability to publish your API Apps into Azure Market Place. Azure Market Place is the public repository for all API Apps that can be consumed freely or by charge.

[this](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Azure-Friday/Azure-App-Service-API-Apps-with-Scott-Hunter) 15 minute video from Channel 9 gives an excellent overview about Api Apps.

Answer (score 2):

To supplement Greg's answer, [Here's an even more recent article describing the differences.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-whats-changed/)

To sum up:

"The key features of API Apps – authentication, CORS and API metadata – have moved directly into App Service. With this change, the features are available across Web, Mobile and API Apps. In fact, all three share the same Microsoft.Web/sites resource type in Resource Manager."

And here's another important note:

"If your API is already deployed as a Web App or Mobile App, you do not have to redeploy your app to take advantage of the new features."

Answer (score 1):

This can depend on what you are trying to do, but you would use a Web API when you are creating a service.  ASP.Net Web API is a framework for building HTTP services that can be consumed by a broad range of clients.  This allows you to build it not only for a web app, but have it open to connect to Android apps, IOS apps, web apps, Windows 8 apps, WPF apps etc..

So if you need a Web Service but you don't need SOAP then you can use Web API.

Comment: I think the user is saying that a web api app is so similar to a web app and in fact in VS we can mix them easily that what makes a web api app unique.  When we deploy a web api or web app to IIS locally there is no difference to anything so why a difference in Azure?

Answer (score 1):

Here my comments:

API app:
    Used for specific functionallity. Triggering that functionality from an URL.
    Can be used to use with GET, POST, PUT, DELETE.
    Can receive parameters at BODY (Json).
    Response with valid status code (fail, sucess.)

Web APP: An application deployed with multiple functionallity, for example
         a catalog for create, update and delete customers or to create a complete ERP.

Function APP: Is very similar to API app,
    Used for specific functionallity. Triggering that functionality from an URL.
    Can be used to use with GET, POST, PUT, DELETE.
    Can receive parameters at BODY (Json).
    Response with valid status code (fail, sucess.)

[image: Comparation table: Web App vs API app vs Azure Functions.]

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can deploy your aspnet webapi on Azure WebApp and a self host on Worker Roles.

On WebApp (former Azure websites), it will be deployed on IIS, so you can take advantage of IIS features.