# Azure API App vs Mobile App vs Web App

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-services, azure, web-applications

Used to write sql server backed web services that exposed xml via SOAP on a hosted server platform. Know how to do that. If I want to take that knowledge to Azure... which model will work best for a sql backend, ADO data, and a web service that a web application and a mobile application can read write data through?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Web API vs Web App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31387073/azure-web-api-vs-web-app)

Answer (score 8):

There was a point in time when there were differences between the different app service types, but that is no longer true.  The [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-apps-why-best-platform/) now states:

> The only difference between the three app types (API, web, mobile) is the name and icon used for them in the Azure portal.

So it no longer matters which app service type you choose to deploy to (unless you care what the icon looks like).

Comment: That's ridiculous, they should just merge them to make things clearer!

Comment: Seems documentation has removed this now

Answer (score -1):

An API app and a Azure Web app will equally work for you. They are both web apps. But one has been optimised for better use of API.