# Is there any azure API App cmdlet?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell

Anyone aware of cmdlet for creating API App in powershell? I tried searching for it, but couldn't find anything. I think `New-AzureRmWebApp` is way to go by passing some `type`, has anyone idea about it?

Comment: See this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49329357/4148708

Comment: Great, thanks. I will give it a try.

Comment: @evilSnobu : it worked, but 2 suggestions in the answer. I will use your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [evilSnobu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4148708/evilsnobu) in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49328159/azure-app-service-apiapp/49329357#49329357,) it worked with slight modification. So I am posting the answer if someone needs it.

```
# CREATE "just-an-api" API App

$ResourceLocation = "West US"
$ResourceName = "just-an-api"
$ResourceGroupName = "demo"

# If we want to create under a specific app plan, we need to pass the server farmid in format
$serverFarmId = "/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/<resource_group_name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/<app_service_plan_name>;

#If nothing is passed inside $PropertiesObject, it create s default app service plan.
$PropertiesObject = @{"serverFarmId"=$serverFarmId}

New-AzureRmResource -Location $ResourceLocation `
    -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject `
    -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
    -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites `
    -ResourceName "just-an-api" ` #removing $ResourceName, as either one is required.
    -Kind 'api' `
    -ApiVersion 2016-08-01 -Force
```