# What is the difference between an API App and a Web App in Azure?

Tags: azure

Please Note: This is NOT a duplicate of [What is the difference between an API App and a Web App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31387073/what-is-the-difference-between-an-api-app-and-a-web-app)

The answer is outdated because the documentation changed and the quoted text was removed from the documentation.

So can someone explain me what the difference between API App and a Web App is? I can't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

API apps in Azure App Service offer features that make it easier to develop, host, and consume APIs in the cloud and on-premises. With API apps you get enterprise grade security, simple access control, hybrid connectivity, automatic SDK generation

Web Apps is the compute resources that Azure provides for hosting a website or web application in App Service. The compute resources may be on shared or dedicated virtual machines (VMs), depending on the pricing tier that you choose. Your application code runs in a managed VM that is isolated from other customers.
Refer: https://www.quora.com/What-is-difference-between-Azure-API-App-and-Web-App

Answer (score 2):

Both API App and Web App are types of [Microsoft Azure App Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/app-service/). These are a platform as a service (PaaS) offerings from Azure.

[API App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/app-service/api/) is specific for developing RESTful APIs with feature like Swagger out of the box. [Web App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/app-service/api/) on the other hand is used to host Web Applications.